# conditional views in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a question that concerns conditional partial-a-like views in AngularJS. The example below isn't very optimal. It also returns an error that belongs to the line `$compile(element.contents())(scope)` that says that I can't use `scope` as a function - but otherwise it won't render everything correctly. The use case is as following:

1. I'm requesting a Route over `$http` that returns a array of objects
2. I'm `ng-repeat` that returned array of objects
3. For every object (lets call it `obj`) a `obj.view_edit` value is given.
4. If the `obj.type` equals `plugin`, a `<plugin></plugin>` directive is inserted

That would look like:

```
 <plugin view="content.view_edit"></plugin>
```

My Directive looks like:

```
 directive('plugin', function($compile) {
    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.view);
        element.html(scope.view).show();
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
    return {
        restrict:"E",
        link: linker,
        scope: {
            view:'='
        }
    }
})
```

Do you have any better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do manual DOM manipulation in your link function to hide/show or `$compile`s until you're dealing with more complexity. Just use the native `ng-if` directive.

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objects">
    <div ng-if="isPlugin(obj)">
        <plugin view="obj.view_edit"></plugin>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!isPlugin(obj)">
        This is not a plugin.
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you would have a function in your scope that the `ng-if` references. This keeps the HTML cleaner and clear of as much logic as possible.

```
scope.isPlugin = function (obj) {
    return obj.type === 'plugin';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed this Problem using your approach with [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) `ng-switch="content.type"` and a `ng-switch-when="plugin"` for every type.